# Export to excel includes dropdownlist

Tags: c#, devexpress

I need to export a `datagrid` into Excel. The exported Excel data can be modified and imported back to a grid.  I am exporting a `datagrid` using Dev Express exporter control(`dx:ASPxGridViewExporter`).

Now I have a scenario where the exported Excel should contain a `dropdownlist`.  For example,  State Master grid exported Excel should contain the country code as a `dropdownlist`, pre-fill the country code into a `dropdown` so that we can restrict the user not to key in a country code.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I am using `ASP.net`,  `C#` and `Dev Express` controls.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?  Are you throwing any exceptions?  Do you have some code that you could post along with your question?  It is hard to provide suggestions when we cannot see the code you are working with.

Comment: look at this link you need to focus on the part where it talks about ValidationData http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/702f77eb-d770-4044-825a-b867f29bbaa9/ now you need to get that to work with your Dev-Express Export. Or you may need to go to the Dev-Express web site they have example code so you need to do a google search